# Ruby on Rails - Stylesheets in /stylesheet directory and not in /assets, no fingerprint in production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

The problem is the following:

On the production website:

```
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application-88627ba4e39c16e7875ecd7dacb14d52.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/stylesheets/stylesheet.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
```

In application.css:

```
*= require_self
(no *= require_tree)
```

In index.html.haml:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
= stylesheet_link_tag "stylesheet", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
```

So the problem is: application.css is working properly, but I don't want it to include every other stylesheet. (I want different stylesheets per subdomain)
So I need to include it in another stylesheet_link_tag, but that doesn't work properly. It isn't in the /assets directory and it doesn't have a fingerprint.
In development, it does work.

How can I fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing your stylesheet from the precompiling targets. Add this to your config/application.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(stylesheet.css)
```

It works in development mode because default settings for this environment will serve assets in the application itself and will compile assets on demand without checking config.assets.precompile setting.

Comment: Thank you! application.rb now looks like this:
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.precompile += %w(*.css)
    config.assets.precompile += %w(*.js)

Answer (score 1):

In `production.rb`, make sure you have:

`config.assets.precompile += ['stylesheet.css']`

so that it gets compiled as well when you run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.